# docker run behavior with commands in different order

Tags: docker

I'm trying to figure out the way docker handles commands presented to it.

For example if I run this the JS app starts fine.

```
docker run ...name etc.. /bin/bash -c "cd /video_recordings/voddirectory; pm2 start app.js; pm2 startup; stunnel; nginx;"
```

However, If I do it like this in a different order

```
"stunnel; nginx; cd /video_recordings/voddirectory; pm2 start app.js; pm2 startup;"
```

The JS app does not run.

What behavior is docker looking for to continue to the next command?

Similarly if I use in my docker file:

```
ENTRYPOINT stunnel && nginx -g 'daemon off;' &&  bash
```

and then do a

```
docker run ...name etc.. /bin/bash -c "cd /video_recordings/voddirectory; pm2 start app.js; pm2 startup;"
```

The JS app never runs.

Comment: This seems like you're trying to run four different processes; why not run them in four separate containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `&&` or `;` between command, shell will execute in order. So, the first command needs to finish first and then the subsequent command run.

**BUT** you call `nginx -g 'daemon off;'` will make it run in the foreground. Therefore, it is never finished running. The commands follows won't run.

However, I am still not sure why `stunnel; nginx; cd /video_recordings/voddirectory; pm2 start app.js; pm2 startup;` does not run as the normal behaviour of Nginx should go background.